# Setting the indices for a 3d mesh in libGDX

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, mesh

i got stuck with a problem in libGDX. I want to create a simple untextured 3d model out of a mesh. This is my code so far to create a tetrahedron:

```
Material material = new Material(new IntAttribute(IntAttribute.CullFace), ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GRAY));
ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
Mesh mesh = new Mesh(true, 6, 20, new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, "test"));
mesh.setVertices(new float[] { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0,
                                0.5f, -0.5f, 0,
                                0, 0.5f, 0,
                                0, 0, 1});

mesh.setIndices(new short[] {0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3});
modelBuilder.begin();
modelBuilder.part("test", mesh, GL20.GL_LINE_STRIP, material);
model = modelBuilder.end();
```

This code works fine but i don't know how to set the mesh's indices for generated vertices.
I currently got a list with Vertices and each Vertex got a list which contains the Vertices with it is connected. 
How i have to set the mesh's indices to realize this connections?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are wanting to only draw the edges, not surfaces:

I don't think it's possible to use a line strip to draw all edges of a tetrahedron without drawing at least one of the edges twice. The shape is not complicated enough to justify trying to use a line strip to optimize it. I think it is rare to have situations where it makes sense to use a line strip or triangle strip.

So change `GL20.GL_LINE_STRIP` to `GL20.GL_LINES`. Now your indices array should be a list of pairs of indices that define line segments. The first two indices define the first segment, the third and fourth indices define the second segment, and so on.

A tetrahedran has six edges, so you should list out all the connections between the points. In the case of a tetrahedran, it's every possible combination of points possible. The indices numbers correspond with the vertices you defined. You defined 12 floats and there are three floats per vertex, so you will have indices from 0 to 3 for the four total vertices.

So an example, although the order of pairs doesn't matter.

```
{
 0,1, //Connect the 1st vertex (-0.5f, -0.5f, 0) to the 2nd vertex (0.5f, -0.5f, 0)
 0,2, //Connect the 1st vertex to the 3rd vertex (0, 0.5f, 0)
 0,3, //Connect the 1st vertex to the 4th vertex (0, 0, 1)
 1,2, //Connect the 2nd vertex to the 3rd vertex
 1,3, //Connect the 2nd vertex to the 4th vertex
 2,3  //Connect the 3rd vertex to the 4th vertex
}
```

This would draw all the edges.

If you want to draw actual triangle surfaces, you should use GL_TRIANGLES instead, and your indices list will need three elements per triangle for a total of 12 elements. Each three elements would define the three corners of a triangle to draw, but you also need to make sure they all wind in the same direction (clockwise or counter-clockwise depending on your culling setting).

Actually, in the case of a simple tetrahedran, you could use a triangle strip, although not if you want to add lighting to it because none of the vertices could be shared between faces due to different normals.